# SSRF trough Gopher

Tags: web-application, http, exploit, vulnerability, ssrf

Gopher protocol is used a lot when exploiting SSRF, but how?

a Gopher URL takes the form:

```
  gopher://<host>:<port>/<gopher-path>
```

but let's take this example:

`gopher://10.10.10.3:80/_POST%20/login%20HTTP/1.1%0aContent-Type:%20application/x-www-form-urlencoded%0aContent-Length:%2041%0a%0ausername%3dtest%26password%3passw0rd12`

why is there a HTTP request as a "path"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the gopher protocol uses the TCP protocol to establish connections to servers, and it uses the following format

```
gopher://<host>:<port>/<bytes to send to server>.
```

So when you send your payload, for example what you mentioned in the post, you establish a TCP connection to 10.10.10.3 on port 80 and send the following bytes to the server:

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 41

username=test&password%3passw0rd12
```

which the HTTP server understands as an HTTP POST request.